# Java Compute C(n,k) and factorial with biginteger

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

I want to compute the answer of C(n,k),such as C(10,2)=10*9/2*1 = 45
If I test my code by small numbers like 10, the code works.
However, when I try to compute C(1000,900), it compiles

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

I've seen someone says it should use `BigInteger`,But after I tried, it still has errors.

For example: I change `int factorial`  into  `BigInteger factorial`,
while the for loop in `cSelect`, I can not change `int i` into `BigInteger` type, 
As result, the answer `up/factorial(y)` has errors.

Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks!!

```
public class Test {

    // Write a factorial function
    static int factorial(int m) {
        int result =1;
        for (int i=2; i<=m; i++) {
            result = result*i;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Caculate C(x,y)
    static int cSelect(int x, int y) {
        int up=1;
        for(int i=x; i>=(x-y+1); i--) {
            up = up*i;
        }
        return up/factorial(y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(cSelect(1000,900));

    }

}
```

Comment: Its says division by 0, look where you divide by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, return value must be `BigInteger`, because result of `C(1000,900)` far exceeds the range on an `int`.

Second, you don't need separate `factorial()` method. Doing the division as you iterate will improve memory footprint by not creating excessively large intermediate values (at cost of doing multiple divisions, but even so it might actually be faster).

Like this:

```
static BigInteger cSelect(int x, int y) {
    BigInteger v = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = x, j = 1; j <= y; i--, j++)
        v = v.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
    return v;
}
```

By counting `i` down and `j` up, there will never be a fraction from the division.

*Test*

```
System.out.println(cSelect(10, 2));
System.out.println(cSelect(1000, 900));
```

*Output*

```
45
63850511926305130236698511142022274281262900693853331776286816221524376994750901948920974351797699894319420811933446197797592213357065053890
```

Comment: Wow!  But I have one question: In the test C(10,2) , how come java knows the "v.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i)) "only has to operate 10*9? In your code you only give scope to j, which is <=y, but you don't give i a scope.

Comment: @ShinYuWu The loop is really `for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++)` with `i` thrown in, so it will loop exactly `y` times.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fairly easy to translate in `factorial`. Start with `ONE`, multiply by the `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` for each `i` in your loop. Like,

```
// Write a factorial function
static BigInteger factorial(int m) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your other function does ***exactly*** the same, plus a division by the result of `factorial(y)`. Like,

```
// Caculate C(x,y)
static BigInteger cSelect(int x, int y) {
    BigInteger up = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = x; i >= (x - y + 1); i--) {
        up = up.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return up.divide(factorial(y));
}
```

With no other changes I get

> 63850511926305130236698511142022274281262900693853331776286816221524376994750901948920974351797699894319420811933446197797592213357065053890

Which I assume is correct.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use BigInteger to do the calculation.

The value you are trying to compute is approximately 6.385051192630516e+139 and it is not representable as a Java primitive integer value.

Even if the result was representable, the reason you are getting divide by zero errors is that the divisor expression `900! ∗ 100!` is overflowing to zero.  You then divide by that zero.

The reason that it overflows to zero is that it is divisible by 2^32 and 2^64.  That can be proven by using some simple algebra to compute the number of factors of 2 there are in 900! and 100!